# ASP.NET and HTML issue

Tags: asp.net, html, css, cross-browser

I have a div inside a repeater (ItemTemplate) with the following markup

```
<div class="bottle listing">
```

Now for some reason this is being rendered as

```
<divclass="bottle listing">
```

Which breaks the page. This is only occurring infrequently and I haven't been able to nail down if it is only occurring in some browsers. Check out this site please:

http://www.myerwine.com.au/whites/chardonnay/4/16.aspx?page=2

I am viewing it in IE8, but I have been told this page is sometimes broken in Firefox and Chrome. When viewing the source in IE see line 415 "divclass="bottle listing"

Here is a portion of my repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repResults" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repResults_DataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="row listing">
            <div class="bottle listing">
                ............
            </div>
        </div>
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

Any ideas??

[image]

Comment: Posted the code that is outputting: `<div class="bottle listing">`.

Comment: I suggest that you chack your code in html validator. http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: I have used a validator and it doesn't find the broken element. However firefox correctly renders this page (for me)

Comment: I see the problem in FF. You need to post the code from the repeater's item template.

Comment: Hi Tim, please see the updated description of my repeater.

Comment: I've used tons of divs inside repeaters and never seen this. Probably something stupid like needing a clean/rebuild or some caching issue. Post up some code?

Comment: Is it significant that it's only the first div in your repeater that happens on, the rest of the repeated divs emit correct html. What happens if you add two spaces or other attributes to that div?

Comment: Actually its the second div this error occurs on.

Comment: I will attempt to add a second space...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the real answer was because I was using a White space filter and that in turn was removing spaces in the wrong places.

Comment: Well... that would certainly do it.

Answer (score 0):

I added a second space

```
<div  class="bottle listing">
```

And it fixed the problem, if anyone can explain why this solved the problem I would love to hear it.

Comment: Could be your IDE or version control, or Mac - Windows conversions that get rid of the space character there